# How to get incoming twilio number?

Tags: twilio

I am trying to create a sip endpoint to handle incoming calls from Twilio. The call procedure is: A uses traditional phone to dial one of my registered Twilio number, a TwimL message associated to the Twilio number will be called, where it sends a  command to my sip endpoint. From the SIP invite message, I can receive user A’s phone number in the “From” field, but I wonder where can I also get my Twilio number? (say I have several Twilio numbers registered, and my sip end might need to response differently based on different numbers).

Answer (score 1):

you should trace back what call you got ( basicly it happens at calls end , but there are ways to get it with echo )

and than just get the [To number](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call)

Comment: Can you explain it in more detail? Can it be done in the SIP world?